# android : when using MediaPlayer to play background music, sound effects are stopped prematurely

Tags: android, background, effects

I'm trying to play background music on my app and occasional sound effects when you kill an enemy and stuff like that.

All the sound effects worked, but then I started using a MusicManager class (similar to this tutorial: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion) to try to play background music and it works, but the sound effects get chopped after half a second or so.

I'm playing the sound effects using:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.fire); 
 mp.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use soundpool instead.
SoundPool can play multiple streams at once at different volumes, speeds, and looping.
MediaPLayer isn't really meant to handle game audio.

I have 2 games published in the market, and both use SoundPool and have no issues.

here these two functions are taken right out of my game.

```
   public static void playSound(int index, float speed) 
{       
         float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, speed); 
}
public static void playLoop(int index, float speed) 
{       
         float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         streamVolume = streamVolume / 3f;
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, speed); 
}
```

that is how easy it is. To take a closer look at this, I only use my playLoop() to play background music, so I lower the volume on it, but you could easily modify the code to manually set the volume each time you play.

also

```
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, speed);
```

the first argument mSoundPoolMap.get(index) is just a container holding all of my sounds. I assign each sound a final number such as

```
    final static int SOUND_FIRE = 0, SOUND_DEATH = 1, SOUND_OUCH = 2;
```

I load thos sounds into those positions and the play them from it. (remember you dont want to be loading all your sounds every time you run one, just load them once.) The next 2 arguments are left/right volume, priority, and then -1 to set to loop.

```
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

this sets my soundpool to 8 streams. the other is the source type and then the quality.

have fun!

Comment: SoundPool for both sound effects and background music? And thanks! =]

Comment: no problem, i threw in some code for you to look over :) dont forget to accept answer if it is good :)

Comment: I was trying out this solution, but now I can't get any of my sound to play. =[ Maybe I'm getting the AudioManager the wrong way? Essentially I'm just doing: `AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);`

Comment: I just found a simple framework someone else created for you to take a look at. (I just don't want to give away all my stuff, hope you understand). http://sgap.springnote.com/pages/5294563.xhtml